# How to make some kind of Automatization Visual Studio, which helps to analize code and can operate with controls labels - not variable names?

Tags: visual-studio

We works in Visual Studio and write programs on C#  .Net  ASP.NET

For making a standard in naming text labels to controls (button, options etc.) we think to write some code analizys program which can analize code (before, of after compilation to IL) and can found in code text strings which used for naming labels, titles,. (or if label text is stored in variable, check value and make a decision, correct that name, or not.

What tool can i use for automation like that?

I have looked up internet, and found a StyleCop, FxCom, Code Analizys systems - but i understand that this systems have rules only for variable names, not label of control.

How can i make add-on to Visual Studio, which can read code (edited in this time by programmer) and make a warnings while compiling project to avoid programmer use for label non-appropriate values?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by _control labels_?

Comment: text near controls that shows to user

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve. Please reformulate your question and add some examples, if you want some answers / feedback.